# how to get the dropdown value?

Tags: php, jquery

Hi  i am using  dropdown for display the timezone.The timezone values are come from database.Whenever the user change the value I need to alert the new timezone.For example if **user change the time GMT+5.30 to GMT+6.30** then **I want to alert GMT+6.30**.Here the the dropdown values coming as an array?What can I do to get the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `select` and you have set values for your options, you can:

```
$("select#dropdown").change(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

To do this, you need the jQuery framework. http://www.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

checkout http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/ plugin for handling select element, very handy.